# Pass data from a UIPickerView in a secondviewcontroller to the first?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

So I have been stuck on this for a week or so, but how does one pass the specific row selected on a UIPickerView from the secondviewcontroller to the first? I need it for a series of if statements in the firstviewcontroller, so I am thinking segues are not the way to go? Sorry if this seems a bit rudimentary, I am brand new to Xcode and objective c in general.

Comment: I'd look up delegation. Implement delegates between your VCs

Comment: Have you tried using delegation? You may want to read up on this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html and then come back if/when you have any specific programming issues.

Comment: Already theres an answer for this problem in this SO PST http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1